# Sign in math, ^, ~

Tags: math-mode

I have a equation like this but i do not know hw to put the sign above h as:
[image]

Any suggestions are highly appreciated !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following code:

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\[
    \hat{\mathbf{o}}=\mathrm{FFT}^{-1}\left(\tilde{\mathbf{i}}(f)/\tilde{\mathbf{h}}(f)*\mathbf{msk}(f)\right)
\]
\end{document}
```

Note that `\tilde` and `\hat` are used to achieve your aim. (Alternatively, you can use `\widetilde` or `\widehat`.)

[image: Result]

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with `\overset`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
     $\overset{\text{\texttildelow}}{\text{h}}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: yes, and how about "^"?